# ajax-datatables-rails gem optimize queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, datatable

I'm using this gem for my project but when I list "father" relation elements, all childs are loading unnecessary and this makes my system very slow (2k records) .

Models:

instrument belongs_to evaluation
evaluation has_many questions

Problem is I'm listing instruments and all questions inside evaluations are being loaded too (+40 per record)

This is the query that gets the records :

```
  def get_raw_records
    Instrument.includes(
      :evaluation => [:assignature,:level, :evaluation_type])
    .references(
      :evaluation => [:assignature,:level,:evaluation_type]
      ).distinct
  end
```

Some simpler queries like have problems on sorting/ordering.

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks

Comment: please check https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_datatables
for more control on your quires

Comment: you want to include nested modals also?

Comment: uzaif sounds interesting but changing gem is my last option, I'm using yadf with this gem

krishnar didnt understand this. regards